# Using .hasNext() to loop an input pair

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and attempting this question where I'm supposed to input a pair of values (two strings *one at a time*) which is meant to loop until I've exited using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>z</kbd>. Only the grade will be used for the switch; the name is just a dummy value.

My expected output will be:
Enter name: (Name is then entered)
Enter grade: (Grade is then entered)

*Code repeats until EOC is hit.*

What is the most effective way to implement a working loop using while (.hasNext())? The code I've tried to make is very flawed, as seen below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

int ACount = 0;
int BCount = 0;
int CCount = 0;
int DCount = 0;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(input.hasNext()) {
        System.out.print("\nEnter name: ");
            String nameInput = input.next();

        System.out.print("Enter grade: ");
            String gradeInput = input.next();

switch (gradeInput) {
                case "A":
                    ACount++;
                    break;
                case "B":
                    BCount++;
                    break;
                case "C":
                    CCount++;
                    break;
                case "D":
                    DCount++;
                    break;
        }

    }

    System.out.printf("%n%nGrade report%n%nA: %d%nB: %d%nC: %d%nD: %d%n", ACount, BCount, CCount, DCount);

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Well, since .hasNext() acts as an input, I'm not too sure on how make the Enter name: etc. appear before it. Compiling the code above gives a initial blank screen, and you have to input something before the "Enter name: Enter grade: appears", and even that both of them are stuck together side to side, with me unable to input them one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this solution is what you are looking for, it switches between asking for the name and grade until you cancel it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd>. Personally I have been coding java for 4 years and never used a switch, so I just used simple if-else statements, also by using just print, not println, the phrase was getting into the var, which is the reason of me using println.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int ACount = 0;
    int BCount = 0;
    int CCount = 0;
    int DCount = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean askingForName = false;
    boolean first = true;
    System.out.println("Enter name: ");
    while(true) {
        if (first) {
            String nameInput = input.nextLine();

            first = false;
            continue;
        }
        if (askingForName) {
             System.out.println("Enter name: ");
                String nameInput = input.nextLine();
                askingForName = false;

        }else {
            System.out.println("Enter grade: ");
            String gradeInput = input.nextLine();

            if (gradeInput.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                ACount++;

            }else if (gradeInput.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
                BCount++;
            }else if (gradeInput.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                CCount++;
            }else if (gradeInput.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {
                DCount++;
            }



             askingForName = true;
        }


        if (!input.hasNextLine())
            break;

    }
     System.out.printf("%n%nGrade report%n%nA: %d%nB: %d%nC: %d%nD: %d%n", ACount, BCount, CCount, DCount);
}
```

Comment: Yes! The code sequence you posted is exactly what I'm looking for. There are issues with the grade counts, but I'll figure it out. Thanks a lot